# Madhyamaka, theravada and mahayana

Tags: theravada, mahayana, academic-buddhism

Why is Mahayana Buddhism not a form of solipsism (epistemological, methodological, metaphysical) if the first school of Mahayana Buddhism was the Madhyamaka school from which then yogachara originated, which is considered solipsism? It turns out that the Madhyamaka school should be solipsism like Mahayana Buddhism itself, or I don't understand something? Also, why is theravada Buddhism not solipsism (methodological, epistemological, or metaphysical) if the Terevada doctrine is completely dependent on one's own experience and awareness? Thanks you

Comment: Why do you keep asking new questions that ask more or less the same as previous questions on solipsism? Are you not satisfied with the answers to those questions?

Comment: Please see [What is the difference between Buddhism, Hinduism and Solipsism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/43807/471), [Why wasn't the Buddha a solipsist?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/29884/471), [Is Buddhism methodological solipsism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/43964/471)

Comment: Recently a Buddhist told me that Buddhism is solipsism.
Theravada is methodological solipsism, yogashara is epistemological, and Mahayama is metaphysical. I want to know if this is true or have I been deceived?

Comment: Please read the answers to previous versions of this question.

Answer (score 2):

> so•lip•sism sŏl′ĭp-sĭz″əm, sō′lĭp-►
>
> n.    The theory that the self is the only thing that can be known and
> verified.
>
> n. The view that the self is the only reality.
>
> n. The belief
> or proposition that the person entertaining it alone exists and that
> other people exist only as ideas in his mind

That being the definition of Solipsism non of the schools of Buddhism will have anything to do with it.

The Buddha refuted most of the solipsistic schools in his time and taught non-self.