# Do Theravada, Mahayana and Vajrayana teach any form of solipsism?

Tags: philosophy, mahayana, western-philosophy

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#AnotHist

Buddhism is sometimes compared to solipsism.

Discussions on this topic can be found on the Internet. I do not understand why Buddhism is sometimes compared to solipsism.

As far as I know, in all schools and sects of Buddhism Theravada, Mahayana and Vajrayana there is a doctrine of anatman (no-self), and in all schools and sects of Buddhism a special role is played by compassion (in the Mahayana there are Bodhisattvas who swear to deprive all people of suffering).

Also, all schools of Buddhism say that each person consists of skandhas. How then can this be solipsism?

As far as I understand, Buddhism cannot teach solipsism at all.

Do Theravada, Mahayana and Vajrayana teach any form of solipsism?

Or is it just that someone doesn't understand what they are talking about?

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate of existing questions. The duplicate questions have been linked. All of those linked questions contain around 16 answers in total. Please see if they answer your question too. I don't see why or how this question would be different from those questions.

Comment: Another possible duplicate with 2 answers: [Is Buddhism methodological solipsism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/43964/471) (itself closed as a duplicate)

Comment: Related: [Why is the Yogācāra school called 'mind only'?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/5547/471), [Do Cittamatra / Yogacara explicitly refute the existence of an external world?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13790/471), [What is the difference between Yogacara Buddhism and Idealism?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10925/471)